# avcapturesessionPreeset640x480 doesn't work on mac

Tags: avfoundation, avcapturesession, facetime

I have to open camera (by avfoundation.framework)

mac is supported AvCaptureSessionPreset640x480 (FaceTime HD)

I try to do this, but camera image resolution is 1280x720 .

- (void)open
  {
  captureSession = [[AVCaptureSession alloc]init];

  [captureSession beginConfiguration];

  ....

  [captureSession setSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480];

  [captureSession commitConfiguration];
  }

why doesn't work avcapturesessionPreeset640x480?

base SDK : OS X 10.9 , OS X Deployment Target OS X 10.7